# Get MS Dynamics CRM current timestamp from a separate web application

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

We're developing a web application that will load inside an iframe in MS Dynamics CRM 2013. Our application will be on a separate web server with a different time zone. How can we retrieve the current timestamp of the MS CRM server using the Organization Service? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by "current timestamp of the MS CRM server", do you mean what time the crm server thinks it is?

Comment: Yes. We need to store the timestamp of our modification to the entity records and this timestamp must match the timestamp of the CRM server.

Comment: records that are modified and saved to crm automatically get their modified timestamp set. Look for a field called "Modified On" in advanced find (same is true for record creates, created on set automatically by crm)

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the logic a bit to use the "Modified On" field. Thanks again.

Comment: no prob. be aware that the crm server stores all timestamps in UTC format or something like that. I don't have time (no pun intended) to google for it but you'll figure it out by studying the timestamps you retrieve and converting according if you need to etc etc